# The Selenium webdriver returns none when scraping the web page for dynamic numbers

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = r"C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
# create new instance of chrome in incognito mode
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

# go to website of interest
browser.get("https://www.moneyweb.co.za/tools-and-data/click-a-company/SOL/")

# get the financial value
value_element = browser.find_elements_by_id('share-tradingdata-o')
values = [x.text for x in titles_element]

print(values)
```

The code above returns none instead of stock price any idea of what I could be missing here. I'm new to the site by the way. Please assist.

Comment: I had some issues before where the element isn't loaded yet. Try searching for the script to wait for the element to appear, I forgot what is the module called. It comes with selenium so there is no need for installing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the element to load using a Wait.

Here's a solution using an Explicit wait:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_path = r"C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
# create new instance of chrome in incognito mode
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

# go to website of interest
browser.get("https://www.moneyweb.co.za/tools-and-data/click-a-company/SOL/")

# wait for the element to load for 10 seconds
try:
    # get the financial value when its populated to the page
    value_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value((By.ID, "share-tradingdata-o"))
    )
    print(value_element .text)
finally:
    # after 10 seconds, maybe give up?
    driver.quit()
```

This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a `TimeoutException` unless it finds the element value to return within 10 seconds. `WebDriverWait` by default calls the `ExpectedCondition` every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully.

You can keep increasing the wait time as suites the condition.

For more on waits, refer to [Selenium Wait Docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Answer (score 0):

Wait the element with text, please use this xpath expression `//span[@id='share-tradingdata-o' and text()!='']`, it should work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_path = r"C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
# create new instance of chrome in incognito mode
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

browser.get("https://www.moneyweb.co.za/tools-and-data/click-a-company/SOL/")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
value_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='share-tradingdata-o' and text()!='']")))
values = [x.text for x in value_element]
print(values)
browser.quit()
```